# How to handle Pinch Effect on CPGraphHostingView(Core-Plot)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I want to handle Zoom-in and Zoom-Out effect (Pinch Effect) on CPGraphHostingView. If somebody has implemented that please give me any clues..!!

Answer (score 1):

Pinch scaling is enabled by default on recent versions of Core Plot (since 0.3). Since the class prefix changed from "CP" to "CPT" in 0.4, I'm assuming you're using an old version of Core Plot. The simplest solution in that case will be to update to a newer version.

Comment: I have upgraded.But "handlePinchGesture"function is not getting called?

Comment: Also This function is also in version 0.3 but nothing is written in it....is there any way to write some logic in it to get zoom effect..?

Comment: What version did you upgrade to?